# Строки Perl

Tags: строки, perl

Добрый день!
Как корректно работать с длинными строками в Perl? Вот мой пример :

```
        $runner_string = q(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <RUNTIME_DOCUMENT>
        <RUNTIME>epgu_result\include\test.runtime.xml</RUNTIME>
        <SETTINGS>epgu_result\include\online.settings.xml</SETTINGS>
        <TEST>
        <TEST_DATA>epgu_result\tests\).
        $u_numb.
        q(online.xml</TEST_DATA>
        <SETTINGS></SETTINGS>
        </TEST>
        </RUNTIME_DOCUMENT>);
```

Ошибка : **Cant find string terminator ">" anywhere before EOF at...** на первой строчке.
Во-первых, непонятно как корректно работать с длинными строками. Будет ли тут учитываться  символ перевода строки? Как исправить ошибку.

PS Работать надо с одинарными кавычками, переменная $u_numb - управляющая строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $u_numb = 100;

my $runner_string = <<HEREDOC;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RUNTIME_DOCUMENT>
<RUNTIME>epgu_result\include\test.runtime.xml</RUNTIME>
<SETTINGS>epgu_result\include\online.settings.xml</SETTINGS>
<TEST>
<TEST_DATA>epgu_result\tests\
$u_numb
online.xml</TEST_DATA>
<SETTINGS></SETTINGS>
</TEST>
</RUNTIME_DOCUMENT>
HEREDOC

print $runner_string;
```

или так )) ищите отличия

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $u_numb = 100;

my $runner_string = q#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RUNTIME_DOCUMENT><RUNTIME>epgu_result/include/test.runtime.xml</RUNTIME>
<SETTINGS>epgu_result/include/online.settings.xml</SETTINGS><TEST><TEST_DATA>epgu_result/tests/#
.$u_numb.q(online.xml</TEST_DATA>
<SETTINGS></SETTINGS>
</TEST>
</RUNTIME_DOCUMENT>);

print $runner_string;
```

Comment: а в чем, кроме разделителя решетки ваш 2й вариант отличается от моего?Все равно не работает.

Comment: @voipp - слеши в обратку.. или экранируйте \\

p.s. мои варианты, оба работают.